# Find rows in a DataFrame that match

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose make a data frame with pandas

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3],"b":[3,4,5]})
```

Now I have a series

```
s = pandas.Series([1,3], index=['a','b'])
```

OK, finally, my question is how can I know `s` is a item in `df` especially I need to consider performance?

ps: It's better to return `True` or `False` when test `s` in or not in `df`.

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
df.eq(s).all(axis=1).any()
# True
```

---

We start with a row-wise comparison,

```
df.eq(s)

       a      b
0   True   True
1  False  False
2  False  False
```

Find all rows which match fully,

```
df.eq(s).all(axis=1)

0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Return True if any matches were found,

```
df.eq(s).all(axis=1).any()
# True
```